# Changing voltage level from an incremental encoder from 5 V to 3.3 V for my Raspberry Pi Pico ADC pin

Tags: level-shifting, raspberry-pi-pico

[image: Edited PICO]

I want to read data from my DC machine through a [Sendix 5000](https://docs.rs-online.com/214e/A700000008261139.pdf) incremental encoder with a Raspberry Pi Pico.

1. Optical encoder with RS422 output and 5 VDC supply.
2. The HIGH output minimum is 2.5 V, LOW output 0.5 V (maximum)

A and B give the angle reading according to page 6 of the datasheet, I believe.

In my schematic, I have connected Port A to PIN 2 and PWMA to PIN 1, Port B ti PIN7 and PWMB to PIN 6, since they are UART Tx an Rx PINS.

Should I connect anything between the PWM pin of the Pico and my gate driver IC as protection?

The incremental encoder I am using has 5 V output and it is TTL compatible.

I would use this IC [74HC4050PW-Q100J](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC4050_Q100.pdf) to bring it down to the logic level of my Pico (3.3 V).

I do not understand this IC's input/output to get proper A and B for my Pico.

How would the connection from the encoder to the Pico work?
When does one need the EN pin on the Pico?

Comment: You don't want to use an ADC input.  The encoder sends pulses that your processor needs to count.  You would use a digital input.

Comment: Use a potential divider to lower the voltage to 3.3 volts. No need to think ICs for this.

Comment: there are some good sources in the net like: https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use 1Mohm resistors on the lines and connect to digital input as JRE mentioned.

The resistors will limit the current and the Raspberry internal ESD protection diodes will limit the voltage. It's not per say "by the book" but works fine.

Another way (better) is to use [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), but you'll have to put double the amount of resistors.

Comment: I believe, i should have mentioned that i speed is a factor. If i need it to work in high frequency.  Wouldn't voltage divider make it slow. That is the reason i wanted to choose the IC. 
Perhaps, I should consider a logic level N-MOSFET.  Would that require a Gate driver?

Comment: A voltage divider is fast, if the RC time is appropriately low. Use resistors with as low values as you see fit. You can use your scope to see how the edges look, if you don't know the parasitic capacitances.